# Call function on First interaction(Click on desktop browsers / Tap on mobile browsers) with DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to call a function only once when the user first interacted with the DOM.

Is there a simple vanilla javascript library / function to do that?

Here is what I come up with so far. Is this the right way?

```
window.addEventListener("click", function onFirstTouch() {
    console.log("function called");
    window.removeEventListener("click", onFirstTouch, false);
}, false);
```

Comment: `function onFirstTouch() {....}` should be an anonymous function, I'm not too sure what exactly you'd expect from the current code as it appears to be defining a new function instead of passing a function as an argument?

Comment: The current code should work fine without any issues. 
`window.removeEventListener("click", onFirstTouch, false);` is run inside `function onFirstTouch()`. So it works fine. Only if his `window.removeEventListener("click", onFirstTouch, false);` was outside of `window.addEventListener("click", function onFirstTouch() {..},false); then it would not have worked as onFirstTouch would be undefined then

Comment: @Derek It *must not* be an anonymous function. OP is doing it right - if it were anonymous, it couldn't be referenced later and removed via `removeEventListener`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance even then, it should be defined outside of the `addEventListener`, which was my whole point

Comment: @Derek

I got that code from this gist. It worked. But I am not sure whether it's the right way to do.

https://gist.github.com/davidgilbertson/045a4aa68eab4d59fa94fe48240e5fb2

Comment: @Derek There's no need for it to be defined outside of the listener though. His code works as is.

Comment: I suppose I can forget how forgiving Javascript can be sometimes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `removeEventListener`, an even easier method (if you're just assigning *one* listener, as in your question and your gist) would be to invoke the `once` option, which is a property of the optional options object you can pass to `addEventListener`.

There's also no need for the `false` parameter, which specifies `useCapture`, which defaults to `false` anyway:

```js
window.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("function called");
}, { once: true });
```